# Ubuntu 22.04 is not booting up when I am booting up my system it shows this

Tags: boot, 22.04

This is what it is showing when I boot and it freezes completely.

[image: Problem when booting my system]

Comment: The first line tells me that the system was not shutdown properly the last time. This is a normal message telling you there is a log file you can look at.